# Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mysql-error-1292

I am trying to insert data, by the query:

```
insert into email (emailAddress, isPreferredEmail, customer_id, upload_id)
select cast(Email as char(100)) a,
       TRUE,
       (select id from customer c where c.dbvehregno=ChassisNo),
       uploadid
  from hyundaiindividualreport
 where id in (select max(id) 
                from hyundaiindividualreport 
               where length(Email>=5) 
                 and uploadid=900 
               group by ChassisNo);
```

But it's throwing:

> ```
>   Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value
> ```

---

Email Table structure:

```
 Table: email
Columns:
email_Id bigint(20) AI PK, 
emailAddress varchar(300) ,
isPreferredEmail bit(1) ,
updatedBy varchar(255) ,
customer_id bigint(20) ,
upload_id varchar(255)
```

Comment: "the syntax of length function was wrong, but its raising that error so i got confused. " is it fixed now? if not provide table structures and some example data from both tables and place it on db-fiddle.com.. if it is fixed you could consider accepting @GordonLinoff answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression does not look right:

```
length(Email >= 5)
```

I think you mean:

```
length(Email) >= 5
```

However, it seems surprising that it would generate that particular error in MySQL.

Comment: This expression will not raise such error (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/50436), it must be something else, MySQL in fact evaluate the boolean expression, then self implicit convert it to a varchar and returns 1

Comment: the syntax of length function was wrong, but  its raising that error so i got confused.